# http: switch source stream (mp4 video)

Tags: node.js, express, video, stream, mp4

Im trying to switch a video source stream to a http client:

```js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();

app.get('/video', (req, res) => {

    console.log("/video hit");

    const video = fs.createReadStream("./video.mp4");
    const intro = fs.createReadStream("./intro.mp4");

    video.pause();
    intro.pause();

    res.writeHead(200, {
        //"content-type": "video/mp4"
        //'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
        'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    });


    intro.pipe(res);

    setTimeout(() => {
        intro.unpipe(res);
        video.pipe(res);
    }, 100); // 3~10 sec the player crashes



});

app.listen(4000);
```

The problem is, the first video starts to play correct, and when the timeout is over, the second video does not start at time (i think buffering) and when the buffer from the player/client is empty the player crashes.

Could the problem with the crahs has something to do with the meta information in the second video ?

As player i have used firefox and vlc.

The reason for that is, i want to display a intro/wating video before the final stream starts (which can happen at a diffrent time)

Comment: I don't think you can switch the source file this simply. Each video file starts with some data which tells the video player how to handle it(what codec to use, resolution, etc). I think the way to switch videos would be to notify the client/player to change the source/url.

Comment: @Molda That's what I thought. What about a "ffmpeg overlay" ? ffmepg = mp4 output stream and if no video comes from a other http stream i display only a overlay placeholder video